# Asp.NET not applying my CSS files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css

My site located in folder **/website**

In browser it opens by url `http://localhost:52912/website/`

My Default page amd master page both located in root catalog

in Default.aspx i include my master page like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default"  MasterPageFile="WTF.master" %>
```

In my WTF.mater i include css file:

```
<link href="~/css/reset.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

when i run the site and look his source code in mozilla, i see css file link as:

```
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

so, full url will be `http://localhost:52912/website/css/reset.css` which is correct

-css file EXISTS

-No errors in firebug like "404 not found - reset.css"

-No errors when debugging project

I can't even open this file by direct link in browser ( `http://localhost:52912/website/css/reset.css` ) or by link in mozilla source code viewer

It returns `http://localhost:52912/website/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcss%2freset.css` 
and i remains on the same page

I tried a whole bunch of  various combinations and advices from google - nothing helps

What the..???

**SOLVED:**
by adding

```
<location path="css">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

in web.config

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you have forms authentication turned on and you haven't allowed that `css` folder public access. Try adding this to the web.config:

```
<location path="css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Tnx pal, my suspicions were justified!

Comment: @sbxmal No probs :) glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have an Authentication issue.
Could you check or post your web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tilde (~) from the link href. It should just be

```
<link href="/css/reset.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```