# ASP .NET not loading CSS

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a similiar problem as the user here: [Asp.NET not applying my CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481147/asp-net-not-applying-my-css-files)

but when adding the code below to my web.config nothing happens.

```
    <location path="css">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

The css file is still not loading. When I try to open it in a web browser by viewing the source, it opens a blank page with the correct URL (http://localhost/css/style.css). The only time when css is applied, is when I run the application from Visual Studio.

My web.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EDCConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EDC;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=web;Password=web" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <location path="css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".css" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if your css file path is correct on web.config? i.e.   <location path="css">, I mean if css folder is not inside any other folder

Comment: Yes, the path is correct. It must be something with IIS on my computer. Some setting or something. Because I copied the source data to another IIS server and it works fine there.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what file structure you may have setup, but it's worth pointing out that your location node does not have the root folder noted:

```
<location path="css">
```

Try

```
<location path="~/css">
```

Or however you have it set up. Failing that, assuming you have a site.master and a bundle.config you can always add the css file there.

Hope it helps, Apex

Comment: Still same... but it must be something with IIS on my computer...Because I tryed code on another IIS server and it works fine there.